# ToS attribution requirements have wrong capitalization

Tags: bug, terms-of-service

[Terms of Service](https://stackexchange.com/legal) section 3, paragraph 2 currently reads:

> d.You will ensure that any such Internet use of Subscriber Content ***Hyperlink*** each author name directly

which means just that "each such use must contain a hyperlink" so the word *hyperlink* should start with a lowercase letter.

This is most likely a bug.

Comment: I would rather say that _hyperlink_ is used as verb, in that sentence: "You will ensure that any such Internet use of Subscriber Content **hyperlinks** each author name directly back to his or her user profile page on the source site on the Network."

Comment: Lawyers aren't bound by the same Rules of Capitalization And Grammar as the Rest of Us.

Comment: @kiamlaluno: Whatever, that still requires a lowercase letter.

Comment: I find it amusing that you, a programmer, consider this a "bug".

Comment: It's probably [tag:status-by-design], as in this is how the lawyers gave it to the dev team, so this is how it should look.

Comment: @chuex: LOL, I usually say "then it's a design defect" in such cases.

Comment: I did downvote this because I initially thought it's kind of a waste of time (people post ridiculously minor "bugs" here all the time), but if you think it makes the TOS confusing then I guess it's legit. I do think you are technically correct.

Comment: @WesleyMurch: With current wording we have some "Subscriber Content Hyperlink" instead - something I've never heard of. Yes, once I've read that three times I've got to the intended meaning.